# jquery validation - calling .valid() method of some element is not clearing the error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation plug-in to validate my forms.

https://jqueryvalidation.org/

When I call .valid() method of some element in another element validation then the current element error message is not getting removed.

Say I have elements E1 and E2 . The validation method for element E1 is Method1.
In Method1 , if I call E2.valid() to programattically trigger validation.
The error message in E1 is not getting removed even thought the element is valid.

Please find the code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Validate IP Address using jQuery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=
"http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready((function() {
            $.validator.addMethod('IP1Checker', function(value) {
                $("#ip2").valid();
                return isValidIPAddress(value);
            }, 'Invalid IP address');

            $.validator.addMethod('IP2Checker', function(value) {
            return isValidIPAddress(value);
            }, 'Invalid IP address');

            $('#form1').validate({
                rules: {
                    ip: {
                        required: true,
                        IP1Checker: true
                    },
                    ip2: {
                        required: true,
                        IP2Checker: true
                    }
                }
            });

            function isValidIPAddress(value) {
            var isValid = /^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/.test(value);
            if (isValid && (value === "0.0.0.0" || value === "255.255.255.255")) {
                isValid = false;
            }
            return isValid;
        }

        }));
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1">
    <input id="ip" name="ip" type="text"  /> 
    <input id="ip2" name="ip2" type="text"  /> 
    <input id="Submit2" type="submit" value="submit" />
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you please provide a fiddle.

Comment: Please enter your Code

Comment: Hi Developer107 and Hmd , I have added the code. If you provide wrong ip say "1.1.1.1S" in the first box and move to next box.It will show invalid Ip address and later if you remove S and still the error message persist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, jQuery v1.4.2 and jQuery Validate v1.7 are ridiculously old (circa 2010) and should be updated.

---

```
$.validator.addMethod('IP1Checker', function(value) {
    $("#ip2").valid();  // <- you shouldn't do this
    return isValidIPAddress(value);
}, 'Invalid IP address');
```

You should not call `.valid()` from within the `.addMethod()` method as it could potentially throw everything into a loop.  The `.addMethod()` method is only intended for creating a new validation rule, not for other functions such as programmatically triggering the validation test.  (The validation test runs *all* rules on a particular field or form.  The validation rule evaluates one particular field against one particular rule.)

You don't even need a custom method for checking IP addresses.  Simply use the `ipv4` rule that's already built into [the `additional-methods.js` file](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/additional-methods.js) of the plugin.

```
$('#form1').validate({
    rules: {
        ip: {
            required: true,
            ipv4: true
        },
        ip2: {
            required: true,
            ipv4: true
        }
    }
});
```

**DEMO**:  https://jsfiddle.net/p5gn6zhe/

---

As far as calling `.valid()` on field #2 inside the custom IP rule for field #1; it's not clearly explained why you'd want to do this.  Are you wanting field #2 validation to depend on whether field #1 is filled out?  If so, then that's something else entirely.

Otherwise, you would trigger `.valid()` using an external handler.

```
$('#ip').on('keyup blur', function() {
    $("#ip2").valid();
});
```

**DEMO 2**:  https://jsfiddle.net/p5gn6zhe/2/

Comment: Thanks Sparky . I resolved the issue by using callback . I called this validation by doing setTimeout($("#ip2").valid(),0);